# How do I get instance id/name from public ip address of VM in azure via python sdk

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python

```
    def get_instance_id_from_pip(self, pip):
    subscription_id="69ff3a41-a66a-4d31-8c7d-9a1ef44595c3"
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(self.credentials, subscription_id)
    network_client = NetworkManagementClient(self.credentials, subscription_id)

    print("Get all public IP")
    for public_ip in network_client.public_ip_addresses.list_all():
        if public_ip.ip_address == pip:
            print(public_ip)

            # Get id
            pip_id= public_ip.id.split('/')
            print("pip id : {}".format(pip_id))
            rg_from_pip = pip_id[4].lower()
            print("RG : {}".format(rg_from_pip))
            pip_name = pip_id[-1]
            print("pip name : {}".format(pip_name))

    for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all():
        vm_id = vm.id.split('/')
        #print("vm ref id: {}".format(vm_id))
        rg_from_vm = vm_id[4].lower()
        if rg_from_pip == rg_from_vm:
            ## this is the VM in the same rg as pip
            for ni_reference in vm.network_profile.network_interfaces:
                ni_reference = ni_reference.id.split('/')
                ni_name = ni_reference[8]
                print("ni reference: {}".format(ni_reference))

                net_interface = network_client.network_interfaces.get(rg_from_pip, ni_name)
                print("net interface ref {}".format(net_interface))
                public_ip_reference = net_interface.ip_configurations[0].public_ip_address
                if public_ip_reference:
                    public_ip_reference = public_ip_reference.id.split('/')
                    ip_group = public_ip_reference[4]
                    ip_name = public_ip_reference[8]
                    print("IP group {}, IP name {}".format(ip_group, ip_name))

                    if ip_name == pip_name:
                        print("Thank god. Finallly !!!!")
                        print("VM ID :-> {}".format(vm.id))
                        return vm.id
```

I have above code to get the VM instance ID from Public ip but its not working. What is real surprising is that for all instances, I am getting x.public_ip_address.ip_address as None value.

I had multiple readthedocs references for python SDK of Azure. but, some how all links not working. Good job Azure :)

Some of them:
https://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.3/resourcemanagementcomputenetwork.html
https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.storage.file.fileservice.html

Second edit:
I got the answer to this and above code will return vm id given the public ip address. Though, you can see it is not absolutely optimized answer. Hence, better answers are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs have moved here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/python/azure/

We made some redirection, but unfortunately it's not possible to go global redirection on RTD, so some pages are 404 :/

About your trouble, I would try to use the publicip operation group directly:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.network.v2017_11_01.operations.publicipaddressesoperations?view=azure-python

You get this one in the Network client, as client.public_ip_addresses

Comment: Thanks @Laurent. Your answer did help me to get to the place I wanted to reach.

Comment: I will change the question body now and put the function method that helped me. Hopefully it will help community and if someone have better way to solve the same. Please update :)